# Is progressive disclosure helpful in the Listing page of kids-fashion-eCommerce? Read the case

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, e-commerce, mobile-web, progressive-disclosure

**Case**:
In the listing page of kids-fashion-eCommerce, most of the items have multiple sizes (6-12 M, 1-2 Y, 2-3 Y, 3-4 Y, 4-5 Y, 6-7 Y, and so on) and multiple colors.

**Journey of user**:
User comes to the Listing page of kids-fashion-eCommerce - He sees the products (name, price, discount, brand is shown with each product image) - When user hovers over the product image; as a **progressive disclosure** (see image below) ; he is additionally shown a list of almost all available colors & sizes along with a [+n] - The [+n] tells him that still more sizes and colors are present that he will be able to see in the Details page.

[image]

**Question**:
In such case, even via the progressive disclosure, I am not able to show the user the entire information (all the available sizes and colors). **Shouldn't I remove the progressive disclosure altogether?**

Comment: Do you think there is a problem with the partial progressive disclosure?

Comment: Side note: I would not use hovering over the image as the way to trigger showing available sizes and colors, that seems unintuitive. I would just have "Sizes: See all", "Colors: See all" shown by default acting as links to display options.

Comment: Why can't you show them all?  Use 2 rows, same as the sizes.

Comment: @MMacD, the problem is that even after using 2 rows for colors & 2 rows for sizes, I still am not able to show all of sizes and colors - please refer to the image attached in the question.

Comment: Does this need to work on mobile? What's you plan for hover on touch?

Comment: I'm confused, I think.  Do you have the option to use more space?  Do you have the option to *not* use partial disclosure?  If you do, then why would you hesitate?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has much to do with progressive disclosure. You are just hiding options that could be equally important to the user. With progressive disclosure advanced options are hidden because they have no priority at first.

You should consider making equally important options like choice of color and size all available at once. If it's an excessive amount of options that would overwhelm your user or just takes too much space you can use categorisation or filters to add some (real) progressive disclosure that adapts to the users needs.

What you have now is just a randomised set of options that possibly hides what could be the trigger for the user to buy an item. There is no benefit in it for neither the customer and the seller.